# Scala abstract type representing type of subclass

Tags: scala

I'm looking for a way to define a method that returns a type T where T = the type of the subclass.

I know I could possibly do this using abstract types, but dislike the overhead of having to redefine T for each subclass.

Some sample code:

```
object Helper {
  def help[A <: MyClass](cls: A): Option[A] = { cls.foo() map { _.asInstanceOf[A] } }
}

class MyClass {
  type T <: MyClass
  def foo(): Option[T] = Some(this.asInstanceOf[T])
}

class ChildClass extends MyClass {
   type T = ChildClass
}
```

Possibly a new language feature has made this easier? Or can I use this.type in some way? It's important to me that I be able to define a helper class that can call into foo in this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are always returning `this`, then you can indeed have as return type `this.type`. Or have you tried it already?

`this.type` is especially useful e.g. when you want to chain calls to the same object, or provide a static guarantee that you will be returning the same object (and not a copy). For instance, `Buffer`s in Scala have the append operation `:+`, which returns a `Buffer[A]`, and `+=`, which returns `this.type`. The former duplicates the mutable sequence; the latter guarantees that you update the original object.

Comment: Any chance you can point me towards some specific syntax that would work given that I need to write Helper.help exactly as is (with the type parameter)? this.type doesn't match A? Also, note that I need to return Option[this.type], and def foo: Option[this.type] = Some(this) doesn't seem to compile. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Pandora Singleton types are never inferred, you have to specify it explicitly: `Some[this.type](this)`.

Comment: Thanks very much! I've run into another glitch since my foo function in practice actually calls out to another object's static method --> follow up question here if you have insights :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886182/scala-this-type-conformance-to-type-parameter-bounds-of-supertype

Answer (score 2):

To follow up on Jean-Phillippe's answer, who wrote his exactly when I'm writing mine, here's the code:

```
trait SomeTrait {
  def foo: this.type = this
}

class UsesTrait extends SomeTrait

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println((new UsesTrait).foo) // prints UsesTrait@<hash value>
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool, this is helpful. Does this extend to Option[this.type]? def foo: Option[this.type] = Some(this) doesn't seem to compile.

Comment: Heh, I eventually ended up with this too. This is one of the most under-documented language features considering how important it is ...

Answer (score 2):

I found the following idiom useful:

```
class MyClass[T] {
  self: T => 
  def foo(): Option[T] = Some(this)
}

class ChildClass extends MyClass[ChildClass]

new ChildClass().foo()
//--> Option[ChildClass] = Some(ChildClass@2487b1)
```

Comment: Yes, but: • it has to be a trait if you want to allow a whole hierarchy of classes, and • it must be covariant in `T`. Overall, more constraints than a simple `this.type`, no?

Comment: @Jean-Philippe Pellet: Yes, looks like. I'm meditating whether it may have advantages, too, but didn't find one.