# Scala this.type conformance to type parameter bounds of supertype

Tags: scala

I'm trying to compile the following code:

```
class MyClass {
  def foo(): this.type = Helper.bar(this)
}

class ChildClass extends MyClass

object Helper {
  def bar[A <: MyClass](cls: A): A = cls
}
```

The resulting compiler error is:

```
 type arguments [MyClass.this.type] do not conform to method bar's type parameter bounds [A <: MyClass]
```

Is there anything I can do to make this compile property with the method signatures provided above? It seems like MyClass.this.type should be a validClass, and I don't want to have to cast twice when calling Helper (once on the way in and once on the way out).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Singleton types are never inferred. You'll have to write

```
Helper.bar[this.type](this)
```

Comment: Ah, I just realized I was testing in the REPL, and if the classes are defined on separate lines in the REPL, I get the compile error, but if they are pasted in on one block, everything seems okay. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why are singleton types not inferred?